# Explicitly disabling video output for an app - it is possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on an app that plays a lot of video. Is there a way to programmatically (through an Obj-C class or a property within the p-list file) disable any kind of external output to a separate display?

Any guidance would be most appreciated. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your app is capable of displaying to an external output in the first place?  I thought that this had to be explicitly done by moving your UIWindow to a UIScreen other than the main screen.